# "Invalid column name" thrown for Spring Data Native JPA Query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have been trying to fix this for a long time and have tried numerous solutions I've found here today and yesterday and still have not been able to solve my problem. This was working fine and then suddenly stopped and I can't get it to go back to working.

I have a Customer entity and it is mapping to a native sql query. I have tried everything from @Column annotations to setting the physical/implicit naming strategies, etc.

When I run the query directly against the mySQL DB it returns the data I would expect it to in the correct format.

My native query repo looks like this:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT CUSTOMER_ID AS customerId, CUSTOMER_NAME AS customerName FROM CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS)", nativeQuery = true)
List<CustomerEntity> getCustomerData();

}
```

My entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerEntity {

@Id
private int customerId;

private String customerName;
}
```

Even though this was working before, now when I try to retrieve the data I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

The stack trace doesn't point to any class nor reveal exactly what the error is. I turned on Hibernate logging to see the query being executed and this is what it shows:

```
Hibernate: 
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ( SELECT
        CUSTOMER_ID AS customerId,
        CUSTOMER_NAME AS customerName
    FROM
        CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS )
```

Complete stack trace:

```
    2023-02-21 18:28:33.292  WARN 8832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 
    99999
    2023-02-21 18:28:33.292 ERROR 8832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] 
    o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Invalid column name
    2023-02-21 18:28:33.322 ERROR 8832 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.    [/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet     [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is     
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
        at 
 
 
 
 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndexPrimitive(OracleStatement.java:4257) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:4215) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:299) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:662) ~[ojdbc8-21.5.0.0.jar:21.5.0.0.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getString(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]     
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getInstanceClass(Loader.java:1949) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1732) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2186) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.14.Final.jar:5.6.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:156) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]      
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]        
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
```

If anyone can offer any insight it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT * FROM CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS`?

Comment: Yes, but that returns all columns. I specifically only want those two (CUSTOMER_ID and CUSTOMER_NAME)

Comment: looking at your @Entity class, it seems you only have those 2 columns. Please specify the table structure and column names(or the naming strategy)

Comment: Yes, but that should be ok as long as I'm only selecting those two columns, correct? The query only returns customerId and customerName.

Comment: depends on the naming strategy you are using in your properties file. If you are trying using ImplicitNamingStrategy then your columns in DB will be stored as columnId (not column_id) and hence you would get `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name`. If you are using PhysicalNamingStrategy then it would store it as column_id

Comment: Table definition:

The table contains the following definition:

    CREATE TABLE CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS
     (
      CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
      CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
             CUSTOMER_ZIP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
      CUSTOMER_LEVEL INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_ID)
     );

Comment: I have tried it with and without the naming strategies. Implicit and physical.

Comment: Even if there were some way to see the result after Hibernate executes the query it would help but it won't tell me anything other than 'Invalid column name'

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace. Which column are you getting error for?

Comment: It doesn't specify. I can't even see the result of the query. I've added the stack trace above.

Comment: Can you try removing `@Entity` and `@Id` from that class once?
The reason I am asking for removing it is, I referred to this [page](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities#entity) where it clearly says, "Entities in JPA are nothing but POJOs representing data that can be **persisted** to the database." In your case we are not persisting, we are just retrieving it.
And if you want an entity, I think you should map all columns to @Entity. Additionally, You may use `@Transient` on columns that you don't want to be persisted.

Comment: Without entity and id, the app will not start. My repository expects CustomerEntity to be a bean.

Comment: What I'm completely lost on is why this worked and with no changes suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Do you mean it worked? If yes, then I might explain the reason ... and if it failed again, whats the new error?

Comment: it failed with the expected error, no bean of type found (@Entity tags it as a bean). If I remove @Id it complains that there is no identifier on the entity. I know it has to be an entity in order for the queried data to be turned into CustomerEntity so I have to keep the annotations. This is a very silly problem and it is making doing something very simple into something very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

All derived tables require an alias, in most flavors of SQL, so your native query should be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID AS customerId,
           CUSTOMER_NAME AS customerName
    FROM CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS
) t;
```

But the subquery doesn't even look necessary, so you may simply use:

```sql
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID AS customerId,
       CUSTOMER_NAME AS customerName
FROM CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS;
```

Your updated Java code:

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerEntity, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT CUSTOMER_ID AS customerId, CUSTOMER_NAME AS customerName FROM CUSTDBO.CUSTOMERS", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CustomerEntity> getCustomerData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried it with both an alias and without the subquery and am getting the same result. I found that by adding a WHERE clause that left me with 0 results (WHERE 1 = 2) it gave me an empty result back with no error but when there are results something in the column mapping is failing.